# Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 109 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Spec"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
create database Uzina

use Uzina

if(object_id('tUzina') is not null)
    drop table tUzina

if(object_id('tDepartamente') is not null)
    drop table tDepartamente

if(object_id('tSpecializari') is not null)
    drop table tSpecializari

if(object_id('tAngajati') is not null)
    drop table tAngajati

if(object_id('tAtributii') is not null)
    drop table tAtributii

if(object_id('tSalarii') is not null)
   drop table tSalarii

create schema Dacia

create table tUzina 
(
    codUzi char(10) constraint PK_Uzina primary key, 
    denumire varchar(50),
    adresa varchar(50)
)

create table tDepartamente 
(
    codDep char(10) constraint PK_Departamente primary key,
    denumire varchar(50),
    codUzi char(10) constraint FK_Uzi foreign key references tUzina
)

create table tSpecializari
(
    codSpec char(10) constraint PK_Specializari primary key,
    denumire varchar(50),
    codDep char(10) constraint FK_Dep foreign key references tDepartamente
)

create table tAngajati
(
    codAng char(10) constraint PK_Angajati primary key,
    nume varchar(50),
    CNP char(13),
    codSpec char(10) constraint FK_Spec foreign key references tSpecializari,
    codJud char(10),
    localitate varchar(20)
)

create table tAtributii
(
    codAtr char(10) constraint PK_Atributii primary key,
    denumire varchar(50),
    tipAtributii varchar(50) not null constraint CK_tipAtributii check(tipAtributii in ('B','0','F')),
)

create table tSalariu
(
    codSal char(10) constraint PK_Salariu primary key,
    codAng char(10) constraint FK_Ang foreign key references tAngajati,
    dataSalariu tinyint,
    salariu char(10)
)

alter schema Dacia transfer dbo.tUzina
alter schema Dacia transfer dbo.tSpecializari
alter schema Dacia transfer dbo.tSalariu
alter schema Dacia transfer dbo.tDepartamente
alter schema Dacia transfer dbo.tAtributii
alter schema Dacia transfer dbo.tAngajati
go



create synonym tUzina for Dacia.tUzina
create synonym tSpecializari for Dacia.tSpecializari
create synonym tSalariu for Dacia.tSalariu
create synonym tDepartamente for Dacia.tDepartamente
create synonym tAtributii for Dacia.tAtributii
create synonym tAngajati for Dacia.tAngajati

insert into tUzina (codUzi,denumire,adresa)
values ('DPPI','Departamentul de Perfectionare al Inginerilor','adresa'),
        ('RDPT','Reprezentanta Delta Plus Trading','adresa'),
        ('RDPA','Reprezentanta Daperom Grup Auto','adresa'),
        ('RA','Reprezentanta Amat','adresa'),
        ('RAD','Reprezentanta Auto Dacia S.A.','adresa'),
        ('UDM','Uzina Dacia Mioveni','adresa')

alter table Dacia.tUzina
alter column denumire varchar(80) not null

select * from tUzina
select * from tAngajati
select * from tDepartamente
select * from tSpecializari

/*
codUzina        denumire                                           adresa
DPPI        Departamentul de Perfectionare al Inginerilor           NULL
RDPT        Reprezentanta Delta Plus Trading                        NULL
RDPA        Reprezentanta Daperom Grup Auto                         NULL
RA          Reprezentanta Amat                                      NULL
RAD         Reprezentanta Auto Dacia S.A.                           NULL
UDM         Uzina Dacia Mioveni                                     NULL
*/


insert into tDepartamente(codDep, denumire, codUzi)
values ('DC','Caroserii','UDM'),
       ('DM','Montaj','UDM'),
       ('DF','Fabricatie','UDM'),


insert into tSpecializari(codSpec,denumire,codDep)
values  ('CRS','Caroserii','UDM'),
        ('MTJ','Montaj','UDM'),
        ('FAB','Fabricatie','UDM')

insert into tAngajati(codAng,nume,CNP,codSpec,codJud,localitate)
values 
('A01','Geani', '1990514123456', 'CRS', 'AG', 'Pitesti'),
('A02','Mirel', '1990514123457', 'MTJ', 'AG', 'Pitesti'),
('A03', 'Ionelus', '1990514123458', 'MTJ', 'AG', 'C.de AG'),
('A04', 'Horatiu', '1990514123459', 'CRS', 'AG', 'Mioveni'),
('A05', 'Sorinel', '1990514123452', 'FAB', 'AG', 'Mioveni'),
('A06', 'Camasuta', '2194434123346', 'CRS', 'AG', 'Topoloveni')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 109
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Spec". The conflict occurred in database "Uzina", table "Dacia.tSpecializari", column 'codSpec'.

Completion time: 2020-03-25T16:02:39.0347149+02:00

So what can I do to this code? I'm a beginner...

Comment: I guess you are trying to insert values in tSpecializari that are not in tDepartamente.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly are getting more errors than you are showing us.  The error occurs because -- given the data you posted -- there would be no records in the **tSpecializari** table due to the foreign key violation that occurs when you try to insert records into THIS table.

Note these two INSERT statements

```
:


insert into tDepartamente(codDep, denumire, codUzi)
values ('DC','Caroserii','UDM'),
       ('DM','Montaj','UDM'),
       ('DF','Fabricatie','UDM')


insert into tSpecializari(codSpec,denumire,codDep)
values  ('CRS','Caroserii','UDM'),
        ('MTJ','Montaj','UDM'),
        ('FAB','Fabricatie','UDM')
```

You are using UDM for the codDep column of the tSpecializari table.  That value does not exist in the codDep column of the tDepartamente table that you have a foreign key on.  So fix this problem and the error that you posted will go away.

Comment: @Davyyd I am glad it helped. Go ahead and mark it as completed if you don't need any further assistance